# How to get value inside list without index?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an app using flutter and dart.

I have a list of objects with the name parameter, and I want to check if the user input is equal to any of the names of objects inside list.

Simply
I want to take input from a user and switch if one of the objects inside a list has this value to add it in a list

I have searched a lot but with nothing.

```dart
void main() {
  Data data = Data();

  String name = 'Messi';
//I want to switch if name equals any name inside players list without index
}

class Data {

  List<Player> players = [

    Player(
    name: 'Messi',
    ),

    Player(
    name: 'Mohamed',
    ),

  ];

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get a filtered list from the list you have, you can do this:

```
players.where((player) => player.name == userInput).toList();
```

If you just want the first occurrence, you can do this:

```
players.firstWhere((player) => player.name == userInput);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method forEach from the lists.

It basically works like this:

```
players.forEach ((player) {
   if(player.name == name){
     your code...
   }
 });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: or more elegantly, `List.where()` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html